# Check multiple conditions using <c:if>

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

How do I write the following statement using JSTL?

```
if (g.length!=0 && g!="null")
```

Comment: Do you mean to test against `null` instead of `"null"` string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this -

```
<c:if test="${not empty g}">
 <!-- Other code -->
</c:if>
```